# Basic number comparison in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm currently trying to implement a sort-of Hilo-based game in prolog, where the basic functionality is based on setting a secret number, and having the user/program guess it's way forward by going off "Too low", or "Too high".

My thought process has been in this: In any other language, I'd think of it something like this:

```
int secret_number = 50;
int guess = Console.ReadLine();

if(guess < secret_number) Console.WriteLine("Too low!");
else if(guess > secret_number) Console.WriteLine("Too high!");
else Console.WriteLine("You found the secret number!");
```

My attempt of reproducing this in Prolog has been different, but is right now sitting at:

```
secret_number(85).

hilo(Guess):-
    Guess < secret_number, write("Too low!"),
    Guess > secret_number, write("Too high!"),
    write("You found the secret number!").

?-hilo(85).
```

But anyone familiar with prolog will see how incredibly incorrect this probably is. First and foremost, we're getting a Arithmetic error saying secret_number is not a function. To counter this, I've tried sending in `secret_number` as a argument rather than using it as a "global" variable (as I look at it), but that doesn't seem to help much. Apart from that, we're also getting a Goal (directive) fail, but I guess that's something to take for granted in this case.

I realise this is very basic but, as I see it, we all got to start somewhere. Any and all help/pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, Prolog doesn't do `if` statements. Each predicate (what you are calling functions) evaluates the statements and tries to make them true. If there are multiple possible truths, you need multiple predicates. Predicates are also self-contained. You can't expect a predicate to know what's in another predicate. Here's a cleaner version of your code (I did not test it, no guarantee that it works).

```
secret_number(85). %initialize secrete number to 85

hilo(Guess):-
    secret_number(Num), %secrete_number evaluates Guess to be 85
    Guess = Num,
    write("You found the secret number!").

%if your guess is incorrect, move on to a different predicates
hilo(Guess):-
    secret_number(Num),
    Guess < Num,
    write("Too low!").

%if the previous two predicates are both false, this one will be evaluated
hilo(Guess):-
    secret_number(Num),
    Guess > Num,
    write("Too high!").
```

Then you need to write a query in a query window:

```
?-hilo(74).
```

Comment: Alright, fair. I tested it and it seems to work. But I guess the only thing I can't wrap my head around is why `secret_number(Num),` is required? To me it only seems like you take one "variable", assign it to another, and then use that "copy" of it, if you will?

Comment: Like I said earlier, each predicate only knows what's in itself. If you want other information, you have to call the predicate that has it. So calling `secret_number(Num)` as a rule will query `secret_number` to see what is a value for `Num` that makes the rule true. That's the only way to get the secret number value. (unless you just want to do `Guess < 85` ).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ISO predicate [compare/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3) and the fact that the comparison operators are just atoms to shorten your code, for instance

```erlang
message(<, 'too low').
message(>, 'too high').
message(=, 'found!').

hilo :-
  read(Guess),
  secret_number(Secret),
  compare(C, Guess, Secret),
  message(C, Msg),
  writeln(Msg).
```

Anyway, if/then/else in ISO Prolog takes this form:

```erlang
hilo(Guess):-
    secret_number(Secret),
    (  Guess < Secret
    -> write("Too low!")
    ;  Guess > Secret
    -> write("Too high!")
    ;  write("You found the secret number!")
    ).
```

Note that (the potentially expensive) secret_number/1 predicate is called just once...